# Simple strtotime math

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to get the total minutes and seconds that have elapsed from the following step by step:

1: `strtotime('now') - strtotime('-1 day');`

2: Ill get something back like **120** lets say...

3: So... 120 = 2 minutes   -- My problem is the remainder though!

4: Examples:

```
    130 = 2 minutes 10 seconds
    130 / 60 = 2.1666~

    121 = 2 minutes 1 seconds
    121 / 60 = 2.0166~

    122 = 2 minutes 2 seconds
    122 / 60 = 2.0366~
```

- 5: So using the example 122, I have 2 minutes, 
         **but how to I grab the 2 seconds from there?**
      I was trying to `explode` on the period, 
         and use the remainder, but that's not right.

PS: I never had a gift for Math.

Comment: Use mod : 122 % 120 gives you 2, like $minutes = floor($time / 60); $seconds = ($time - 60 * $minutes) % 60;

Comment: "now - 1 day"?  What exactly is this supposed to result in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use DateTime math (php >= 5.3):

```
$d1 = new DateTime(strtotime('now'));
$d2 = new DateTime(strtotime('-1 days'));

$diff = $d1->diff($d2);

echo "{$diff->i} minutes, {$diff->s} seconds\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)::[`diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) which returns [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
   $dt = new DateTime();
   $dt2 = new DateTime("-120 seconds");
   $diff = $dt->diff( $dt2 );
   echo( $diff->format("%i min and %s sec") );
```